# primary key value showing none instead of integer value in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Here is my code

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title text ,author text,year integer ,isbn integer)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO book(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def views():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
    rows=c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

connect()
insert("MAHA","Madan",34,90909)
print (views())
```

my output is

```
[(None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), 
(None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34,
 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Mad
an', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAH
A', 'Madan', 34, 90909), (None, 'MAHA', 'Madan', 34, 90909)]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Python 3.6.2. You should give the exact version you are using.

Comment: Remove books.db. I think you already  have book table with different schema.

Comment: Try without the `IF NOT EXISTS` part of `CREATE TABLE`. You might, as suggested, be looking at an older definition of your table.

Comment: Serge Ballesta its 3.7.1

Comment: how can i connect to database then

Comment: MrGumble though I might be looking for older defination of my table..but how can primary key value be none?

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
```

You have to add the `NOT NULL` property so that it'll return the integers in incrementing order.